# How to port the default table in liferay to mySQL?

Tags: liferay

I'm using liferay 6.2 server. Moving my local development to a web server.

I've deployed the local development code on the web server successfully. But this code is using the default hypersonic DB provided by liferay.

I want to change it and point it to mySQL database. I understand that I need to start off from portal-ext.properties. But, I was trying to understand what all tables were created in the hypersonic DB.

How to replicate that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferay provides this feature built-in.

You can see that feature under Control Panel > Server Administration > Data Migration.

Here you can provide jdbc database related information.

For reference link :[Data Migration](https://www.liferay.com/web/alexander.chow/blog/-/blogs/cmis-and-database-migration)